# Junit using ant

Tags: java, ant, build, junit4

I have a class that looks like this:

```
---imports---

class ErroringClass {

/* methods*/
main{}

}
```

**Update**

```
public class TestErroringClass {

static ArrayList<Integer> arrayTestTimes;
static ErroringClass main = new ErroringClass ();

@Test
public test{}

 .
 .
 .
}
```

Testcase: initializationError took 0.002 sec
    Caused an ERROR
The class ErrorTestClass is not public.
java.lang.Exception: The class ErrorTestClass is not public.
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

Testcase: initializationError took 0 sec
    Caused an ERROR
Test class should have exactly one public constructor
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

```
<!-- Testsuite -->
<target name="test" depends="compile" >
    <junit fork="yes" 
           description="Unit Tests"
           showoutput="true"
           printsummary="true"
           outputtoformatters="true" filtertrace="on">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath.test"/>
            <pathelement location="${main.build.dir}"/>
            <pathelement location="${test.build.dir}"/>
        </classpath>

        <test name="ErrorTestClass" outfile="./output" >
            <!-- <formatter type="brief" usefile="true" /> -->
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="true" />
        </test>
    </junit>
</target>
```

Trying to run my test from ant and not getting them to see all my files that are in one file to keep the source as accessible following the rules in design.  What am I missing?

**Updated**

```
Testsuite: ErrorTestClass
Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.104 sec 
------------- Standard Output ---------------
[]
------------- ---------------- ---------------
Testcase: Test1 took 0.001 sec
Testcase: Test2 took 0 sec
Testcase: Test3 took 0 sec
Testcase: Test4 took 0 sec
Testcase: Test5 took 0 sec
Testcase: stringTestNull took 0.001 sec
Testcase: stringTestTrue took 0 sec
Testcase: assertNullTest took 0 sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because `ErrorTestClass` has package level access (default visibility modifier). Change it to `public class ErrorTestClass`.

Comment: I have the test running but they aren't actually running them .   The times are too short. Updated the code with the different compiled classes after making them both public.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried something simple like putting in some `System.out.println` statements in the tests to make sure? The fact it used to throw an Exception, and now you've corrected that by making it public and the Exception has gone, suggests to me that it is running the tests. Perhaps you could call `fail()` from the tests and re-run them?

Comment: The System.out.print isn't possible using junit task to return information.

Comment: Did you try calling `fail()` from inside the body of your tests to determine whether or not they are running? (`import static org.junit.Assert.fail;`)